# Writing formula in textpad from R without quotes

Tags: r

I have a vector of formulaes in R in string format. Example

```
eqns <- c("a = b + c","d= a + d + x","k = a + f + g")
```

How can I get an output in textpad in the form

```
a = b + c
d= a + d + x
k = a + f + g
```

It is important the equations are written without quotes in notepad and stacked upon one another as they will be used further in this form for inputing equations in package sem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
cat(paste(eqns, collapse = "\n"))
```

You can also use the file argument of cat to output the equations to a file:

```
cat(paste(eqns, collapse = "\n"), file = "eqns.txt")
```

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly what I wanted